# Laravel Socialite Facebook error: "POST https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token resulted in a `400 Bad Request` "

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth

I've made social login using `Laravel Socialite` for facebook and it was working fine. I haaven't changed anything and now it's not working. It shows this error when trying to login:

`Client error:`POST https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token`resulted in a`400 Bad Request`response:
{"error":{"message":"This IP can't make requests for that application.","type":"OAuthException","code":5,"fbtrace_id":"D (truncated...)`

I haven't changed setting in my facebook app, nor in my code.
My code is the following:

```html
Route::get('login', ['as' =>'getLogin', 'uses'=>'Auth\AuthController@getLogin']);
Route::get('handleProviderCallback/{provider}', 'Auth\AuthController@handleProviderCallback');
```

```html
public function login($provider = false)
    {
     if(!$provider) {
            $user = Input::all();
            $auth_user = new AuthenticateUser();
            $is_logged = $auth_user->findByEmailOrCreate($user, false);
            if($is_logged) {

                Session::put('user', Auth::user());
                Session::put('user_id', Auth::user()->id);
                Session::put('email', Auth::user()->email);
                Session::put('name', Auth::user()->name);

                return redirect()->intended('dashboard');
            }
            return redirect('/')->withInput()->with('error', 'Wrong username or password!');
        }
        return \Socialite::with('facebook')->redirect();
    }
    
    public function handleProviderCallback($provider=false) {
        if(Input::has('code')) {
            $user = \Socialite::with($provider)->user();
            $auth_user = new AuthenticateUser();
            $provider_user = $auth_user->findByEmailOrCreate($user, $provider);
            Session::put("user", array($provider_user));
            Session::put('user_id', $provider_user->id);
            Session::put('email',$provider_user->email);
            Session::put('name',$provider_user->name);

            return redirect('dashboard');
        }
    }
```

Problem appears in `handleProviderCallback` method in this line:

`$user = \Socialite::with($provider)->user();`.

When I only dump this:
`$user = \Socialite::with($provider)`

it shows data but when it is used like that to get user data it returns the error:

`$user = \Socialite::with($provider)->user();`

In `config/services.php` I've set settings like this example:

```html
  'facebook' => [
        'client_id' => 'my-client-id-from-fb-app', 
        'client_secret' => 'my-secret-code-from-fb-app', 
        'redirect' => 'http://my-example-domain/my-site/handleProviderCallback/facebook'
    ],
```

In my facebook app I've set in settings:

`App Domains: my-example-domain,
Privacy Policy URL: http://my-example-domain/my-site/,
Site URL: http://my-example-domain/my-site/handleProviderCallback/facebook,
Valid OAuth redirect URIs: http://my-example-domain/my-site/handleProviderCallback/facebook`

Comment: Still looking for solution. Do you have any update?

Comment: I haven't worked on this test project soon. Do you have any solution?

Comment: I change config/services.php about facebook.redirect from http to https, after that use the command:

php artisan config:clear

I take a lot of time to debug.

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, I didn't check the request at all to see what's returned but someone on Larachat helped me solve this problem.

All I had to do before getting the user and handle the request was to add the following code in the callback method:

```
if (!$request->has('code') || $request->has('denied')) {
   return redirect('/');}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this message on my local machine after getting secret key value from .env file

```
ClientException in RequestException.php line 111:
enter code here Client error: `POST 
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/oauth/access_token` resulted in a `400 
Bad Request` response:
{"error":{"message":"Error validating client 
secret.","type":"OAuthException","code":1,"fbtrace_id":"ID"}}
```

As expected problem was with secret key, I pasted it wrong, so after double check and right copy/past from fb everything worked.

Hope this info will help somebody.

Answer (score -2):

What's your Laravel version?

I've experienced the exact same problem and after going through the socialite package and make little changes, it solves the problem. You might want to give it a try.

**vendor/laravel/socialite/TwoFacebookProvider line 81**

Replace this

```
parse_str($response->getBody(), $data);
```

with

```
$data = json_decode($response->getBody(), true);
```

It seems like the data isn't adding

Comment: it still not woking.

Comment: You should never edit Vendor files.

Comment: @Jigs1212 If you have better solutions, please do share it would really help.

Comment: that is not a solution, this will just cause further problems and will stop working on first composer update.